# Sequence contains more than one matching element - composite key

Tags: entity-framework-5

When you try to create a one-to-many relationship from the use a composite key, I get the error "the sequence contains more than one matching element"

Help me please!

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PracticePilotScoringInfo>()
                    .HasKey(info => new { info.DriverName, info.Control,info.VehicleClass, info.ScoringInfoId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<PracticeScoringInfo>()
            .HasKey(info => info.Id)
            .HasMany(info => info.PracticePilotScoringInfos)
            .WithRequired(info => info.ScoringInfo)
            .HasForeignKey(info => new { info.DriverName, info.Control, info.VehicleClass, info.ScoringInfoId });



        public class PracticeScoringInfo : ScoringInfo
{
    public int GrandPrixId { get; set; }
    public GrandPrix GrandPrix { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PracticePilotScoringInfo> PracticePilotScoringInfos { get; set; }
}


public class PracticePilotScoringInfo : PilotScoringInfo
{
    public string DriverName { get; set; }
    public ControlType Control { get; set; }
    public string VehicleClass { get; set; }
    public Guid ScoringInfoId { get; set; }
    public virtual PracticeScoringInfo ScoringInfo { get; set; }
}


        public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;

    }
```

Comment: "the sequence contains more than one matching element" is usually a LINQ exception thrown by `Single()` or `SingleOrDefault()` method. are you using it somewhere?

Comment: error occurs when the Update-Database.

PM> Update-Database -Verbose
Using StartUp project 'Vmso'.
Using NuGet project 'Vmso'.
Укажите флаг "-Verbose", чтобы отобразить инструкции SQL, применяемые к целевой базе данных.
System.InvalidOperationException: Последовательность содержит более одного соответствующего элемента
   в System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)

Comment: Post your Database-Migrations code as well, then.

Comment: I have difficulty in inserting the complete code

 public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;

    }

Comment: Me do not care where the error, me care possibility of such a construction

Comment: Is `ControlType` an `enum`?

Comment: yes, ControlType is enum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I'm not identified in Fluent API mapping.
declaration a below  is working fine

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<ScoringInfo>()
            .HasKey(info => info.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PracticeScoringInfo>()
            .HasKey(info => info.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PilotScoringInfo>()
                    .HasKey(info => new { info.DriverName, info.Control, info.VehicleClass, info.ScoringInfoId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<PracticePilotScoringInfo>()
            .HasKey(info => new { info.DriverName, info.Control, info.VehicleClass, info.ScoringInfoId });
```